# PHP - Sum distinct arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have been trying all day to sum below array, based on the value and only get the distinct values.

Here is my input array:

```
[
    {
        "commoditycodes": "6204.4400",
        "statisticalvalue": 1152.6,
        "cvr": "DK35425950"
    },
    {
        "commoditycodes": "6204.4400",
        "statisticalvalue": 542.4,
        "cvr": "DK35425950"
    },
    {
        "commoditycodes": "6104.4300",
        "statisticalvalue": 1827,
        "cvr": "DK35425950"
    },
    {
        "commoditycodes": "6114.3000",
        "statisticalvalue": 5211.36,
        "cvr": "DK37968552"
    },
    {
        "commoditycodes": "6114.3000",
        "statisticalvalue": 798.64,
        "cvr": "DK99999999"
    }
]
```

I am trying to "gather" all arrays that have the **same** `cvr` value, but still show it distinct based on `commoditycodes`. Like this:

```
{
    "commoditycodes": "6204.4400",
    "statisticalvalue": 1695,
    "cvr": "DK35425950"
},
{
    "commoditycodes": "6104.4300",
    "statisticalvalue": 1827,
    "cvr": "DK35425950"
},
{
    "commoditycodes": "6114.3000",
    "statisticalvalue": 5211.36,
    "cvr": "DK37968552"
},
{
    "commoditycodes": "6114.3000",
    "statisticalvalue": 798.64,
    "cvr": "DK99999999"
}
```

]

As you can see, from the input, the first two results from my array have:

- Identical commodity code
- Identical CVR value

We then sum the `statisticalvalue`.

The third result have the same CVR value as the two first, **however** the `commoditycode` value is different - so this is an unique value.

The fourth and fifth elements of my arrays is both unique as well.

So basically, I am trying to sum `statisticalvalue` where:

- CVR value is the same
- Commodity code is the same

I have tried below:

```
$result = [];

foreach ($array as $val) {
    //Not a duplicate cvr code
    if (!isset($result[$val['cvr']])) {
        $result[$val['cvr']] = $val;
    //Duplicate cvr code.
    } else {
        $result[$val['cvr']]['statisticalvalue'] += $val['statisticalvalue'];

    }
}
```

But that returns below, which only take the unique `cvr` values - but not the `commoditycodes`:

```
[
    {
        "commoditycodes": "6104.6300",
        "statisticalvalue": 68701.56,
        "cvr": "DK35425950"
    },
    {
        "commoditycodes": "6104.6300",
        "statisticalvalue": 21108.95,
        "cvr": "DK37968552"
    },
    {
        "commoditycodes": "6114.3000",
        "statisticalvalue": 798.64,
        "cvr": "DK99999999"
    }
]
```

I am totally lost on how to check for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an array with a complex index `$val['cvr'].'|'.$val['commoditycodes']`

```
$result = [];

foreach ($array as $val) {
    $index = $val['cvr'].'|'.$val['commoditycodes'];
    if (!isset($result[$index])) {
        $result[$index] = $val;
    //Duplicate
    } else {
        $result[$index]['statisticalvalue'] += $val['statisticalvalue'];
    }
}
```

If you want to make result array with numeric index, add after loop:

```
$result = array_values($result);
```

Comment: This should work well if you don't need to preserve the format of your array elements.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If he wanted to do aggregation for the elements with these two similar keys, he will need to preserve the same object structure, as he has shown in the snippet after `that returns below`. His code does not do that either though.

Comment: @splash58 this works beautifully! Such a "simple" solution. Thanks a lot!!! Really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!